# Weird Pings To Active Directory Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, ubuntu-10.10

Alright so I have my Winwodws Server 2008 acting as both an Active Directory and DNS server. Right now I have two clients, a Windows 7 VM and an Ubuntu 10.10 Server VM, all on the same network. They are both using the Windows Server for DNS. Though, when I try to ping the AD server, here's the results:

```
Windows 7

C:\Users\Chiggins.AD>ping ad.chigs.me

Pinging ad.chigs.me [2002:8a57:b303:c:6428:442:be05:719f] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 2002:8a57:b303:c:6428:442:be05:719f: time=10ms
Reply from 2002:8a57:b303:c:6428:442:be05:719f: time<1ms
Reply from 2002:8a57:b303:c:6428:442:be05:719f: time=1ms
Reply from 2002:8a57:b303:c:6428:442:be05:719f: time<1ms

Ping statistics for 2002:8a57:b303:c:6428:442:be05:719f:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 10ms, Average = 2ms
```

---

```
Ubuntu

root@ubuntu:~# ping ad.chigs.me -c 5
PING ad.chigs.me (192.168.137.211) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=1 ttl=128 time=1.53 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=1 ttl=127 time=1.59 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=1 ttl=128 time=1.60 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=1 ttl=127 time=1.60 ms (DUP!)
From 192.168.137.1: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Network(New nexthop: 192.168.137.211)
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=2 ttl=128 time=0.783 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=2 ttl=128 time=0.851 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=2 ttl=127 time=0.856 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=2 ttl=127 time=0.862 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=3 ttl=128 time=0.769 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=3 ttl=128 time=0.784 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=3 ttl=127 time=0.808 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=3 ttl=127 time=0.821 ms (DUP!)
From 192.168.137.1: icmp_seq=4 Redirect Network(New nexthop: 192.168.137.211)
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=4 ttl=128 time=15.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=4 ttl=128 time=15.7 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=4 ttl=127 time=15.9 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=4 ttl=127 time=15.9 ms (DUP!)
From 192.168.137.1: icmp_seq=5 Redirect Network(New nexthop: 192.168.137.211)
64 bytes from 192.168.137.211: icmp_req=5 ttl=128 time=1.29 ms

--- ad.chigs.me ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, +12 duplicates, 0% packet loss, time 9910ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.769/4.559/15.960/6.264 ms, pipe 2
```

The Windows 7 machine is correctly joined to the Active Directory server, but now I'm trying to work on connecting the Ubuntu machine to AD. What can I do on my Ubuntu machine to make the connection "correct" ?

Thanks

Comment: Try throwing a larger ping packet at the server from windows 7, do you see any errors if you send a ping with -l 1400?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows ping is being sent over an IPv6 6to4 address, where the Ubuntu ping is being sent straight up IPv4. I'd check your v4 DNS for what ad.chigs.me is listing as a host and make sure that's correct. Then double-check the settings on the AD server to make sure the v4 IP information makes sense.